# chrome redirect when connecting to network with authentication redirect

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, redirect

i often save multiple tabs in my browser, sometimes, i'll make the mistake of opening when connected to a network that requires authentication and redirects, such as a pubilc network at a cafe, starbucks, in the lounge areas of my apartment building, etc.

the url location changes for all of the tabs without any history state/back button.

1. how can i prevent the redirect from occuring?
2. is there a way of authenticating before opening the browser application?
3. how can i recover the locations, without having the scour my history index?